# Composer memory limit exhausted

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-nova, laravel-7

i have business hosting at All-Inkl.com, unfortunately i cannot use composer there anymore. The support wrote more that I have reached the limit of 1.5 GB and more is not possible.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)
```

Now my question is, is there any way to let the Composer update or install it piece by piece, so that it frees the memory in between or is there any other solution to run my Laravel app on the server?

Currently the following packages are in the Composer JSON. And there are a few more planned.

```
    "require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "benjaminhirsch/nova-slug-field": "^1.2",
    "cloudcake/nova-snowball": "^1.2",
    "ctessier/nova-advanced-image-field": "^1.0",
    "davidpiesse/nova-toggle": "^0.0.6",
    "digitalcloud/nova-address-field": "^1.3",
    "dillingham/nova-detail-link": "^1.0",
    "ebess/advanced-nova-media-library": "*",
    "ek0519/quilljs": "^0.1.9",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "gabrieliuga/laravel-mail-log": "*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "inspheric/nova-email-field": "^1.42",
    "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
    "jubeki/nova-card-linkable": "^1.1",
    "kabbouchi/nova-logs-tool": "*",
    "khalin/nova-link-field": "*",
    "klepak/nova-dynamic-page-title": "^1.0",
    "laraning/nova-time-field": "^0.2.5",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/nova": "*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.1",
    "m-a-k-o/nova-custom-table-card": "^2.0",
    "maatwebsite/laravel-nova-excel": "^1.2",
    "normanhuth/nova-menu-order": "1.0.2",
    "ofcold/nova-sortable": "^1.0",
    "opanegro/field-nova-password-show-hide": "^1.0",
    "raiym/instagram-php-scraper": "^0.9.7",
    "richardkeep/nova-timenow": "^1.0",
    "sbine/route-viewer": "^0.0.6",
    "sidis405/nova-installed-packages": "^0.1.8",
    "spatie/laravel-activitylog": "^3.11",
    "spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.8",
    "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^7.19",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.11",
    "spatie/nova-backup-tool": "*",
    "spatie/schema-org": "^2.12",
    "vyuldashev/nova-permission": "*",
    "whitecube/nova-flexible-content": "^0.1.16"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5",
    "sirbrillig/phpcs-import-detection": "^1.2",
    "sirbrillig/phpcs-variable-analysis": "^2.8",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.5"
},
```

Comment: No. Because I have already done all that, but the limit of the server is simply reached.

Comment: Do you already skip the development packages? `composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev`

Comment: And maybe the following thread helps: https://community.contao.org/de/showthread.php?65036-All-Inkl-Mal-wieder-Fatal-error-Allowed-memory-size

Comment: No. I don't use Contao and doesn't have the contao settings.

Comment: You should do `composer update` only locally, and push your composer related files to server, then just `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the limit at -1 and 99999.The "All-Inkl" webhosting servers are just too weak and already reached their limits. I will now change the provider and temporarily copy the packages manually to the server.